# Websocket load balancing doesnt work even if using AWS Load Banacing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, load-balancing, amazon-elb

Currently I hava a "Load Banacer" and two EC2 nodes. I'd like to set them up in a way so that it's possible to use WebSocket via port 9090 and HTTPS via port 443.

At the moment, Websocket is running independently on both EC2 nodes which are ws://54.250.154.x:9090 and ws://54.250.154.y:9090

From what I've found on the internet, there's a solution for this one which is by enabling Proxy mode for AWS. However, I'm not really sure how to set it up.

So, can you guide me how to config LBC to connect 2 websocket servers using load balancing?

I'll very happy if you give me guidance by an example?

Answer (score 0):

AWS elastic load balancers do not support websockets via HTTP, only via HTTP. To accomplish what you want you'll need to set up two listeners on your ELB:

1. Port 443 on the ELB forward to whatever you want on the instances (you didn't specify in the question). This should configured as HTTPS on the front end and HTTP or HTTPS on the back end, depending on what your instances are expecting.
2. Port 9090 on the ELB forwards to port 9090 on the instances. For the protocol you'll use TCP (or TCP+TLS, if your websocket connection uses SSL). This will permit websockets to work.

Comment: Thank you for support.
I was set up two listeners:
1. Port 443 on ELB forward: HTTPS (443) on front end => HTTP(80) on back end
2. Port 9090 on ELB forward: TCP(9090) on front end => TCP 9090 on back end
And web socket is working but consecutive disconnect and reconnect.
I was search on internet and find solution is enable proxy of ELB.
But when enable proxy of ELB, web socket don't working.
I want ask about configure web socket and ELB.